# esp8266 esp01s EEPROM and flashing

Tags: esp8266, eeprom, flash

which flash option do I need to take to use EEPROM?

Can I flash with 1MB and no SPIFFs and still write data to EEPROM?

thanks T

Answer (score 1):

> Can I flash with 1MB and no SPIFFS and still write data to EEPROM?

Yes. The EEPROM emulation is saved into different part of the flash, not to SPIFFS.

```
|--------------|-------|---------------|--|--|--|--|--|
^              ^       ^               ^     ^
Sketch    OTA update   File system   EEPROM  WiFi config (SDK)
```

the memory map is from [esp8266 SPIFFS docs](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filesystem.html)

> which flash option do I need to take to use EEPROM?

There is no special option in Tools menu for EEPROM emulation. Only use the library.